# Chrome mobile browser memory error when upload file

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, file-upload, input-type-file, low-memory

### Hi,

Is it possible to create a custom file upload to prevent chrome's `unable to complete previous operation due to low memory` error"?

It works perfectly on the desktop version of chrome. Actually I use an **input type="file"** control and I got this error on Chrome mobile browser:

---

[image]

Comment: This is still an issue... Doesn't seem to be fixed yet. Chrome should be able to do this since we can clearly share images from our phone with other apps like gmail and Facebook.

Comment: Did anyone come across a solution for this yet?

Comment: I am getting this error on my phone. I don't know if it's just my phone but I would also appreciate a programmatic solution to the issue. Can I scale the image down in javascript before upload? What are my options? No good answers that I can see address this.

Answer (score 4):

One answer I found was to go into developer tools from your settings menu. Scroll the bottom and make sure that "Don't keep activities " is turned OFF. many people in other forums said that solved the problem for them, but when I did it, it made absolutely no difference at all. You can give it a try.

Comment: this solution worked for me. It seems that "unable to complete previous operation due to low memory" isn't a correct error message. when, on mobile, i have to choose files it opens up another app but it closes google chrome's background process

Comment: I confirm this works, Android 12 @ Pixel 5.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to try is to go to `Settings > Apps > Chrome > Clear Cache`. This may help but other wise this may be a problem with chrome itself or even your phone.

Answer (score 0):

On my phone in developer settings the "Don't keep activities" option was already turned off. So I switched it to on. Then closed everything out even on the apps overview screen I closed everything out.

I let my screen timeout so it went black and put the lock screen back up. Just so that I waited a few minutes before trying it again. So then I unlocked my phone went to System Settings > Developer Options > Don't keep activities option and turned it back off.

Then I tried to upload the picture one more time on Chrome. I was ready to give up after this.

Answer (score 0):

We can handle this problem using the steps :
Settings > developer option > disable "don't keep activities" this if enabled the option

And the problem is solved....

Comment: Hi Pankaj, welcome to stack overflow! It looks like the solution you posted has already been posted earlier by someone else. If you have anything to add to an already existing answer that you believe is correct upvote that and feel free to add a comment inline